# C++ - using GTest value-parameterized tests with structs causes valgrind errors

Tags: c++, struct, valgrind, googletest, packing

Can you help me understand what is going on here with GTest and struct packing?

The problem seems to be related to how a struct is packed when used as a value in a value-parameterised test in GTest. Taking the straightforward approach of instantiating a struct for each value results in valgrind errors relating to uninitialised values.

Here's the code concerned:

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

struct TestItem
{
    const char * aString;
    int anInt0;
    int anInt1;
    int anInt2;
};

class TestBase : public ::testing::Test, public ::testing::WithParamInterface<TestItem> {};

TEST_P(TestBase, TestAtoi)
{
    TestItem item = GetParam();
    std::cout << sizeof(TestItem) << std::endl;
    ASSERT_FALSE(0);   // actual test doesn't matter
}

INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P(
        TestBaseInstantiation,
        TestBase,
        ::testing::Values(
                TestItem { "0", 0, 0, 0 }
));
```

When this is compiled and linked (I built GTest with cmake):

```
g++ gtest_valgrind.c -o gtest_valgrind -I gtest-1.7.0/include -L gtest-1.7.0/build -lgtest -lpthread -lgtest_main -std=c++11
```

And then executed with:

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes ./gtest_valgrind
```

The following output is produced:

```
==17290== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==17290== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==17290== Using Valgrind-3.10.0.SVN and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==17290== Command: ./gtest_valgrind
==17290== 
Running main() from gtest_main.cc
==17290== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==17290==    at 0x55B89F1: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:180)
==17290==    by 0x55BC6F6: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1660)
==17290==    by 0x55E1578: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:119)
==17290==    by 0x55C3531: snprintf (snprintf.c:33)
==17290==    by 0x41F107: testing::(anonymous namespace)::PrintByteSegmentInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x41F1AA: testing::(anonymous namespace)::PrintBytesInObjectToImpl(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x41F252: testing::internal2::PrintBytesInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B8E: testing::internal2::TypeWithoutFormatter<TestItem, (testing::internal2::TypeKind)2>::PrintValue(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B63: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& testing::internal2::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, TestItem>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, TestItem const&) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B3E: void testing_internal::DefaultPrintNonContainerTo<TestItem>(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B19: void testing::internal::DefaultPrintTo<TestItem>(char, testing::internal::bool_constant<false>, TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409ADB: void testing::internal::PrintTo<TestItem>(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17290==    at 0x404AAE: gtest_TestBaseInstantiationTestBase_EvalGenerator_() (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290== 
==17290== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17290==    at 0x55B89F8: _itoa_word (_itoa.c:180)
==17290==    by 0x55BC6F6: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1660)
==17290==    by 0x55E1578: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:119)
==17290==    by 0x55C3531: snprintf (snprintf.c:33)
==17290==    by 0x41F107: testing::(anonymous namespace)::PrintByteSegmentInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x41F1AA: testing::(anonymous namespace)::PrintBytesInObjectToImpl(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x41F252: testing::internal2::PrintBytesInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B8E: testing::internal2::TypeWithoutFormatter<TestItem, (testing::internal2::TypeKind)2>::PrintValue(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B63: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& testing::internal2::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, TestItem>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, TestItem const&) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B3E: void testing_internal::DefaultPrintNonContainerTo<TestItem>(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B19: void testing::internal::DefaultPrintTo<TestItem>(char, testing::internal::bool_constant<false>, TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409ADB: void testing::internal::PrintTo<TestItem>(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17290==    at 0x404AAE: gtest_TestBaseInstantiationTestBase_EvalGenerator_() (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290== 
==17290== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17290==    at 0x55BC742: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1660)
==17290==    by 0x55E1578: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:119)
==17290==    by 0x55C3531: snprintf (snprintf.c:33)
==17290==    by 0x41F107: testing::(anonymous namespace)::PrintByteSegmentInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x41F1AA: testing::(anonymous namespace)::PrintBytesInObjectToImpl(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x41F252: testing::internal2::PrintBytesInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B8E: testing::internal2::TypeWithoutFormatter<TestItem, (testing::internal2::TypeKind)2>::PrintValue(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B63: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& testing::internal2::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, TestItem>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, TestItem const&) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B3E: void testing_internal::DefaultPrintNonContainerTo<TestItem>(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B19: void testing::internal::DefaultPrintTo<TestItem>(char, testing::internal::bool_constant<false>, TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409ADB: void testing::internal::PrintTo<TestItem>(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409AA6: testing::internal::UniversalPrinter<TestItem>::Print(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17290==    at 0x404AAE: gtest_TestBaseInstantiationTestBase_EvalGenerator_() (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290== 
==17290== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17290==    at 0x55B9659: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1660)
==17290==    by 0x55E1578: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:119)
==17290==    by 0x55C3531: snprintf (snprintf.c:33)
==17290==    by 0x41F107: testing::(anonymous namespace)::PrintByteSegmentInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x41F1AA: testing::(anonymous namespace)::PrintBytesInObjectToImpl(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x41F252: testing::internal2::PrintBytesInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B8E: testing::internal2::TypeWithoutFormatter<TestItem, (testing::internal2::TypeKind)2>::PrintValue(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B63: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& testing::internal2::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, TestItem>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, TestItem const&) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B3E: void testing_internal::DefaultPrintNonContainerTo<TestItem>(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B19: void testing::internal::DefaultPrintTo<TestItem>(char, testing::internal::bool_constant<false>, TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409ADB: void testing::internal::PrintTo<TestItem>(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409AA6: testing::internal::UniversalPrinter<TestItem>::Print(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17290==    at 0x404AAE: gtest_TestBaseInstantiationTestBase_EvalGenerator_() (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290== 
==17290== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==17290==    at 0x55B96DC: vfprintf (vfprintf.c:1660)
==17290==    by 0x55E1578: vsnprintf (vsnprintf.c:119)
==17290==    by 0x55C3531: snprintf (snprintf.c:33)
==17290==    by 0x41F107: testing::(anonymous namespace)::PrintByteSegmentInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x41F1AA: testing::(anonymous namespace)::PrintBytesInObjectToImpl(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x41F252: testing::internal2::PrintBytesInObjectTo(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B8E: testing::internal2::TypeWithoutFormatter<TestItem, (testing::internal2::TypeKind)2>::PrintValue(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B63: std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& testing::internal2::operator<< <char, std::char_traits<char>, TestItem>(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, TestItem const&) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B3E: void testing_internal::DefaultPrintNonContainerTo<TestItem>(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409B19: void testing::internal::DefaultPrintTo<TestItem>(char, testing::internal::bool_constant<false>, TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409ADB: void testing::internal::PrintTo<TestItem>(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==    by 0x409AA6: testing::internal::UniversalPrinter<TestItem>::Print(TestItem const&, std::ostream*) (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==17290==    at 0x404AAE: gtest_TestBaseInstantiationTestBase_EvalGenerator_() (in /home/davida/git/gitlab/fcdm/lwm2m.git/gtest_valgrind)
==17290== 
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from TestBaseInstantiation/TestBase
[ RUN      ] TestBaseInstantiation/TestBase.TestAtoi/0
24
[       OK ] TestBaseInstantiation/TestBase.TestAtoi/0 (76 ms)
[----------] 1 test from TestBaseInstantiation/TestBase (126 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (246 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
==17290== 
==17290== HEAP SUMMARY:
==17290==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==17290==   total heap usage: 239 allocs, 239 frees, 46,622 bytes allocated
==17290== 
==17290== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==17290== 
==17290== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==17290== ERROR SUMMARY: 20 errors from 5 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

That's a lot of output, but essentially I think it's indicating that there's something unusual about the struct that is instantiated due to the `TestItem { "0", 0, 0, 0 }` line in `INSTANTIATE_TEST_CASE_P`.

Note also that the size of TestItem is output as 24. On a 64-bit system, I'm not quite sure how to reconcile this. 8 bytes for the `char *`, and 4 * 3 = 12 bytes for the `int` members. If they are aligned to 8 byte boundaries, this ought to be size 24 + 4 = 28 bytes (or 32 if including packing). If they are aligned to 4 byte boundaries, then this ought to be 20. There's something I don't understand here about struct packing.

The valgrind warning can be eliminated by packing the struct differently. For example, all three of these modifications result in a clean valgrind run:

Using #pragma pack:

```
#pragma pack(1)
struct TestItem
{
    const char * aString;
    int anInt0;
    int anInt1;
    int anInt2;
};
```

That outputs `20`.

Using GNU g++ packing attribute:

```
struct TestItem
{
    const char * aString;
    int anInt0;
    int anInt1;
    int anInt2;
} __attribute__((packed));
```

That outputs `20` too.

Lastly, adding a dummy value to the struct:

```
struct TestItem
{
    const char * aString;
    int anInt0;
    int anInt1;
    int anInt2;
    int anInt3;   // add an extra member
};
```

That outputs `24`.

I have a fair amount of project code that uses this exact technique for value-parameterized tests, and in all cases valgrind will complain if one of the avoidance strategies is not used.

I'd like to know if there's something fundamentally wrong with my approach of creating values for this test, or is this a consequence of something gtest does with instantiating test cases? Or, most unlikely, is this a gtest bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of `sizeof` for the `TestItem` structure is a consequence of compiler [structure alignment and trailing padding](http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/#_structure_alignment_and_padding).

From the link above:

> [...] It is the first address following the structure data that has the **same
>   alignment as the structure**.
>
> The general rule of trailing structure padding is this: the compiler
>   will behave as though the structure has trailing padding out to its
>   stride address. This rule controls what sizeof() will return.
>
> Consider this example on a 64-bit x86 or ARM machine:
>
> ```
> struct foo3 {
>     char *p;     /* 8 bytes */
>     char c;      /* 1 byte */
> };
> struct foo3 singleton;
> struct foo3 quad[4];
> ```
>
> You might think that `sizeof(struct foo3)` should be 9, but it’s actually 16. The stride
>   address is that of (&p)[2]. Thus, in the quad array, each member has 7
>   bytes of trailing padding, because the first member of each following
>   struct wants to be self-aligned on an 8-byte boundary. The memory
>   layout is as though the structure had been declared like this:
>
> ```
> struct foo3 {
>      char *p;     /* 8 bytes */
>      char c;      /* 1 byte */
>      char pad[7];
> };
> ```

That explains why you are getting 24 for `sizeof(TestItem)` since the trailing padding will align the structure to a multiple of `sizeof (const char*)`, which is 8.

This trailing padding bytes are uninitialized and that is what valgrind reports. Gtest is running some code in order to print the actual value of the `TestItem` parameter when a test fails. This could be confirmed if you make your test pass and valgrind doesn't show the error.

When you force the compiler to use a specific alignment or add a new member to the structure so that the structure doesn't need any trailing padding, valgrind doesn't find any uninitialized bytes in the `TestItem` instances.

Gtest usually calls `operator<<` when printing values and falls back to print the raw array of bytes in the object if it's not available. That's probably why the uninitialized trailing padding bytes are getting accessed. So you may also get rid of the valgrind errors by defining `operator<<` for `TestItem`.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. However the test is passing - `ASSERT_FALSE(0)` will succeed, so no dump of the data is printed. But I think your point is still sound - the test framework must be scanning through the data according to `sizeof` and reading uninitialised values at the padding.

Comment: @meowsqueak So Gtest is trying to print the test parameter value even when the test passes. That's weird, because you cannot see the actual value printed in standard output, right? Did you try to define `operator<<`?

Comment: Yes, I think it is at least doing an snprintf on the value, even though it doesn't print it. Maybe it prepares the output so that the function that actually runs the test can easily print the pre-cooked description if necessary. I have the source, I _could_ find out if I needed to. Your idea of defining `operator<<` works as expected, and eliminates the valgrind error. It's much more useful than a buffer dump anyway, so I'll probably use this throughout the project.